# On $C=\{z:|z|=r\}$ show that $\int_C \frac{dz}{1+z^2}=-2\arctan r$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

If $C=\{z:|z|=r\} (r\neq 1)$, then show that 
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{1+z^2}= \begin{cases}
-2\arctan r, & \text{if 0<r<1} \\[2ex]
\pi - 2\arctan r, & \text{if 1<r}
\end{cases}$$

This is an exercise from the chapter on Cauchy's Integral Formula. I do not know however, how to apply the formula to solve this. I know $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ is a derivative of the $\arctan z$ function, but this has a branch cut inside $C$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand. By Cauchy's Theorem, the answer is $0$ when $r<1$, and by the Residue Theorem it's $0$ when $1<r$.

Comment: I agree. I tested the integral brute force computationally for both $r = 0.5$ and $r = 2$. Both times the contour integral evaluated to zero, contradicting the stated answer. Looks like a faulty exercise!